# Is this the correct behavior for rounding with BigDecimals?

Tags: java, rounding, scale, bigdecimal

I am trying to round BigDecimals like this: 5.46597 -> 5.46,  I thought the code below does this for me, but not.

I tried it with BigDecimal.round and BigDecimal.setScale.

```
BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal(5.46597); // whole number: 5.4659700000000004393996277940459549427032470703125 
bD.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN); // 5.47
bD.round(new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)); // 5.47
```

Isn't this should be 5.46, or what do I misunderstood?

Comment: If you're constructing a `BigDecimal` from a double-precision floating-point literal, the value of the `BigDecimal` will not match exactly the decimal number you started with. If you use `new BigDecimal("5.46597")` (notice the quotes) does it give you the result you expect?

Comment: Try using the String constructor instead: `BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal("5.46597");`

Comment: I think the problem is that you incorrectly assume that only the next significant digit is used for rounding. That's not the case, the whole remainder is considered. @LuiggiMendoza That's not the issue, it will produce same result.

Comment: In other words: the answer is **yes**, it is **a** correct behaviour for rounding. But you obviously want some weird, in any aspect incorrect, behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HALF_DOWN only rounds down when the actual value is exactly half-way between the two possible rounded values. I.e. 5.46500 -> 5.46. On the other hand 5.4650000001 -> 5.47 because that's nearer to 5.47 than 5.46.

Perhaps what you're looking for is `RoundingMode.DOWN`, which always rounds down.

Comment: nah, I have to calculate the rounding with only one digit, so always down is not good for us. I will probably cut down the unnecessary digits then like :  5.46597 => 5.465 => 5.46. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BalázsSipos: what you describe is DOWN, however. It truncates (for positive values), just like you do manually.

Comment: yes, but it will always round down then. You see the system we have to mimic a bit is rounding like this: 5.46697 => 5.47,  5.46597 => 5.46, 5.46497 => 5.46, when scaling to two. So it only cares about that one digit after the digits I need.

Comment: But you are right, this will be what I need:

`bD.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)`

Comment: @BalázsSipos it sounds as if you might be trying to emulate an incorrectly rounding system by also rounding incorrectly in the new system. It would be strange for an actual user requirement to be like that.

Comment: @Balázs is there is a truncate function in the library then use it to chop all but first three digits, then round down 2 digits.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It's not a new system, we just need the same results for comparing purposes. But nvm, thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 3):

Rounding with `BigDecimal` using `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` is defined in JavaDoc as "*ROUND_HALF_DOWN - Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down.*" [Documentation ROUND_HALF_DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_DOWN) [Documentation RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_DOWN)

For `BigDecimal.valueOf("5.46597").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` the nearest neighbors are `5.46` and `5.47` with distances of `0.00597` and `0.00403`.
So the distance to `5.47` is smaller (nearer) than to `5.46` which results in rounding to `5.47`.

Comment: Ah I see... totally misunderstood the documentation, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

First: using the constructor with a double value, immediately introduces the approximation error of every floating point.

Using

```
BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal("5.46597");
bD = bD.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN); // 5.47

BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal("5.46500");
bD = bD.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN); // 5.46
```

one gets an exact fixed point number with 5 decimals.

HALF_DOWN rounds down on .500000... not any fraction more, just the 5er border.

> Logical rounding will happen to its nearest integer, above a half will be rounded up, below a half will round be rounded down. On the **exact half** the international math standard says: round up, but logically (the same distance) it can be either: HALF_UP or HALF_DOWN. As the effect *only* relates to the exact half, testing should not be done with a double constructor, that probably yields a value a tiny bit above or below the exact half.

Also you forgot the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN and RoundingMode.HALF_UP work same way when truncating portion is > 0.5, for example here,

```
BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal(5.46597);
bD.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);//5.47
bD.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP; //5.47
```

Because the truncating part after 2 decimal place (**597**)-> 0.597 is greater than 0.5.
This is what the specification says for HALF_DOWN

> "Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both
> neighbors are equidistant, in which case round down. Behaves as for
> RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is > 0.5; otherwise, behaves
> as for RoundingMode.DOWN."

If your requirement is like below

```
BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal(5.46597);
bD.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);//5.46
```

Then use below line which was suggested by  @Balázs Sipos himself.

```
bD.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
//first part would give 5.465 then the second part would produce 5.46
```

That should work. cheers!